# jQuery draggable table row resizes table in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-draggable, tablerow

I have made a table row draggable with jQuery.  It works as expected (mostly) in Firefox and IE.  However, in Chrome it resizes the original table for some reason.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: function(event, ui){
            var ret = jQuery(this).clone();
            var width = jQuery(this)[0].offsetWidth;
            var myHelper = [];
            myHelper.push(
'<table style="width:' + width + 'px; background-color:green;">');
            myHelper.push(ret.html());
            myHelper.push('</table>');

            helper = myHelper.join('');
            return helper;
        },
        axis: 'y',
        revert: true,
        start: function(event, ui){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    });
});

</script>

<html>

<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
<tr class="drag">
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
<td> one </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
<td> two </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
<td> three </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
<td> fourve </td>
</tr>

<tr class="drag">
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
<td> six </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

I also made [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buzd7/) base on the previous code.  In chrome it resizes the table.  However, if I go to inspect the table, it snaps back as soon as I click it.  What's the deal Chrome?  How do I keep it from resizing the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Andrew, according to [the jQuery doc for draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-appendTo) (options > appendTo),

> The element passed to or selected by the appendTo option will be used
>   as the draggable helper's container during dragging. By default, the
>   helper is appended to the same container as the draggable.

The problem, I theorize, is that your new table row is being added to the old table and Chrome is updating based on the width of that.  Thus, if you set the appendTo option to a containing div, that will solve your problem!  Here is the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/buzd7/7/).

Comment: Thank you! I was having this very issue and the solution you outlined solved my problem.